# FFmpeg - how to configure H264 encoder to output 1 packet after 1 frame (no B frames)

Tags: ffmpeg

Is it possible to configure FFmpeg encoder such that when I call:

avcodec_send_frame

I can then call:

avcodec_receive_packet

and receive the packet?

Right now I have to call avcodec_send_frame a few dozens times before avcodec_receive_packet returns any valid packet. In other words I would like the latency to be reduced to 0.

Comment: Switch to using x264 directly, and use the low latency callbacks.

Comment: What do you mean by "using x264 directly"? And how to use low latency callbacks? Any resources you could point to, please?

Comment: It’s documented in the x264.h file.

Comment: Apparently I don't have such file. Is it part of FFmpeg?

Comment: It’s the first link when you type h.264 into google.

Comment: Sorry “x264.h” in google. (Autocorrect changed it)

Comment: What happens with preset ultrafast? Specifically rc_lookahead=0

Comment: @szatmary: So you're suggesting to dtich ffmpeg in favour of x264?

Comment: @Gyan: ultrafast reduced the latency to about 4 frames IIRC, down from about 54 (sic!) on default

Comment: Anyway, I think I found a solution: av_opt_set(codecContext->priv_data, "tune", "zerolatency", 0); I don't really appreciate the char/text nature of setting a property